# How to target select box in jQuery validate errorPlacement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, errorplacement

If I had an input of type "radio", I would target it like this:

```
if (element.attr("type") == "radio")
```

How do you target a select box? I've tried:

```
if (element == "select")
```

but that doesn't work. I know it's got to be something simple, but I just don't know the syntax.

Comment: Try dumping "element" to the console to see what properties it contains for "select".

Comment: I'm pretty sure its element.val() last time I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `element` refers to the whole object, you can't just compare it to `select` with a comparison operator `==`.

Simply use the `.is()` method for this...

```
if ( element.is('select') ) { ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/18xogtk3/**